# Ember refresh models from another controller

Tags: ember.js

I have an ApplicationController in which when "Ember.select" change value I want to refresh some models.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
needs: ['abstractAuth', 'widgets', 'modalWindows', 'chatCompose', 'chatModal', 'about', 'contacts'],
selectedDomainAlias: {},
selectedDefaultValue: { Id: 2 },

onSelectedDomainAliasChange: function () {
    var self = this;
    var getSelectedDomain = this.get("selectedDomainAlias.domainName");
    $.get('/SetCookies/Cookies?domains=' + getSelectedDomain, false)
        .then(function() {
            self.send("domainChanged");
            self.get('model').reload();
            var contacts = App.controllerFor('contacts').store.find('contact');
            self.get('controllers.contacts').set('model', contacts);
        });
}.observes('selectedDomainAlias.length')});
```

`self.send("domainChanged")` and `self.get('model').reload()` work correctly.

I also have model "Contact", which I should refresh. `App.controllerFor('contacts').store.find('contact')` - receives a model from backend. But I couldn't refresh correctly "Contact" model.

If at first I have two contacts in model. And when I try replace this two contacts per one contact, this contact added as third contact, but I want to get only one contact. How can I refresh "Contact" model correctly?

Comment: I wonder where you are learning Ember from. This style is about two years old.

Comment: I'm a beginner. Change the data in ember from the old project

Comment: It would be good if you update your ember-data version.

Answer (score 0):

`find` method returns Promise, so do it in `then` method.

```
var contacts = App.controllerFor('contacts').store.find('contact').then(function(result){
 self.get('controllers.contacts').set('model', result);
});
```

Currently `find` is private method.